# React native typescript how to receive route params

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

i want to pass the param `userRef` to the `UserProfile` screen. This is my RootStackParamList

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
    Login: undefined;
    Home:undefined;
    NewPost:undefined;
    MyQuestions:undefined;
    Profile:undefined;
    Search:undefined;
    UsersProfile:{
       userRef:string
    }
};

export type propsStack = NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>
```

I'm passing the userRef param as

```
 onPress={() =>
                    navigation.navigate("UsersProfile", {
                      userRef: "Some Name",
                    })
                  }
```

I'm trying to receive it as

```
 const {userRef} = useRoute().params
```

It's giving me this error

> Property 'userRef' does not exist on type 'Readonly<object |
> undefined>'

I imagine i have to type the useRoute, but i'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Though you probably already resolved this, this is for other people like me 10 minutes ago.

First and foremost: annotate your route variable like so:

```
const route: RouteProp<{ params: { variable: Type } }> = useRoute();
```

Then `route.params` is `ReadOnly<>`, but the inner type can be extracted using:

```
const innerVariable: Type = route.params.variable
```